# Add page dynamically to my web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I will publish my web site very soon, but I am wonder if I want to add more screens, will I have to republish the whole site again, while users use it

is there a way to do that dynamically using another web page to upload it

any idea Best regards

Comment: "using another web page to upload it" - I'm not sure what you mean by this.  Can you please explain in a little more detail?  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHoerster I want to be able at future to update my web site and update my site to avoid the Publish the whole site again

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.Net MVC you can make an action that takes a string, and that string can be the name of an HTML file you just render.

There are security issues with this approach, but I've used it in the past to not have to publish the site when I wanted to add static content.

Comment: I need to add a new asp.net mvc page is it what you mean

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a local version of the site that you can work on offline. Dreamweaver makes it very easy to upload your entire local version to overwrite the remote version.

Alternatively, if your website requires a database or server, you can install XAMPP which is a great package to get you started with this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your controllers are in your assemblies. Alternatively you could just upload the dll to your bin directory and copy over the new view to the correct views folder.

Comment: Yes, I think you'll use an ftp account to upload files so upload new asp.net files or Views and let other pages refer the new one by editing links or menus

Answer (score 0):

When hosting your website to a third party server normally you'll have an `FTP account`. and on the server there is what normally called control panel, a software that helps you upload new files easily and perhaps helps you edit file contents.

To exercise this try a free account [Somee.com](http://www.somee.com)

Answer (score 0):

Once you published your first version of your site, you can add more functionalities by creating new mvc areas and pushing them to the bin of your site. The only thing you suffer in this case is a restart of your site.

If you don't have any logic or processing needs for these new pages, you can still define a route to a specific folder with static html pages.

The last option (not the cleaner but the one that fits better to your needs), should be to have a route where you pass the name of the view you want to show. Then you can add more views to your site while online without redeploying or restarting.

```
public class mycontroller : Controller
{
   public ActionResult MyDynamicView(string template)
   {
       var mymodel = SomeprocessingHere();
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(template)
          return View(mymodel); //call only default view with the model
       return View(template,mymodel); //else try to load 
   }
}
```

To finish you only need to map a dedicated route to that, something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "DynamicPages",
                "Dyna/{template}",
                new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "MyDynamicView", template = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

And store your `[template-name].cshtml` files in `/Views/mycontroller` (or where else you define).

Note: that is not clean in relation with what the MVC pattern is design for but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of publishing the complete website/webapplication, you can publish the newly added
or updated pages only while creating the pulished pages. Use the below highlighted option 
in the publish screen.

[image]

So uploading will be required for the required pages only.